# Creating JSON data using SwiftyJson for MultipartFormData request in Alamofire 4

Tags: ios, swift3, alamofire, multipartform-data, swifty-json

I need to send a MultipartFormData .Post Request using Alamofire 4.

The JSON and File data needs to be sent.

I am having a hard time converting SwiftyJson object to type Data object.

SwiftyJSON looks like this:

```
var json: JSON = JSON([ "Name" : "Ben", "UserID" : 2, "Username" : "benji"])
```

Alamofire 4 request looks like this

```
service.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
            MultipartFormData.append(userData, withName: "userInfo")
            MultipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "File")    
            }, to: url) { (encodingResult) in
                switch encodingResult {
                case .success(let upload, _, _):
                    upload.responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
                    }
                case .failure(let encodingError):
                    print(encodingError)
                }
            }
```

My Question is how do I convert SwiftyJson Object to Type Data so I can append it to mutlipartformdata?
I have tried following but they do not seem to work and I can not find a solution online:

```
json.rawData()
json.rawString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out there is/was a bug with json.rawString in SwiftyJSON stated in link below:

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/645

Making fields "implicitly unwrapped" will fix this issue:

```
    var data = JSON([
                "name": _name.text,
                "code": _code.text,
                "iconId": _id])

//data.rawString() will return nil

    var data = JSON([
                "name": _name.text!,
                "code": _code.text!,
                "iconId": _id])
//data.rawString() will return correct result
```

After this I can simply use it as follows:

```
self.service.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
            MultipartFormData.append((data.rawString()?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))!, withName: "trackerInfo")
            MultipartFormData.append(fileUrl, withName: "File") 
        }, to: url) { (encodingResult) in
            switch encodingResult {
            case .success:
                print(encodingResult)
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }
        }
```